# Programmatic docstrings in Visual Studio Code for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'd like to programatically alter docstrings in some of my functions. I'd love for the updated docstrings to display in visual studio code. Is this possible? For example, let's say I have this decorator:

```
def wraps(m, sep="\n"):
    """
    Use another function's docstring
    """
    def _decorator(func):
        if func.__doc__ is None:
            func.__doc__ = m.__doc__
        else:
            func.__doc__ = sep.join([func.__doc__, m.__doc__])
        return func
    return _decorator
```

However, these are not applied in the VS code intellisense. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: functools.wraps would be ok if necessary but also is not supported. Sample function:

```
@wraps(core.otherfunc)    
def newfunc(base, **kwargs):
    """Returns data from :func:`~core.otherfunc`"""
    return core.otherfunc(base, **kwargs)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need the joining bit instead of just replacing? Because if not, you can just use `functools.wraps` out of the stdlib, and at least some IDEs/plugins have special casing for that. (I don't know if ms-python for VSCode does, but it might be worth testing, if it's acceptable.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the intellisense provided by Jedi to pick up the modified docstring without essentially executing code since you can't infer the modified docstring from the AST.

Comment: Is there any possibility for future, that code could be evaluated for help tooltip?
Similiar way like Pylance run code to get type hints... (working even with syntax errors)
I understand that it is kind of monkey patching, but i believe that could be beneficial. Same way as edited docstrings can be displayed in generated sphinx docs, also VS Code Help tooltip could display updated __docs__ even with performance penalty of calling function and implementing some logic...

Comment: For Jedi you would have to ask the Jedi developers. As for Pylance, you would need to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release.